# Is there a reverse of yank-last-arg/insert-last-argument?

Tags: bash, command-history

`yank-last-arg` / `insert-last-argument` is probably better known by its usual shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>. It's very nice to navigate through the last argument of earlier commands, but if you're navigating a little too fast it's easy to miss the argument you wanted, and then it seems you have no other choice but to start all over again. This slows down the navigation, so I hope there's a command to **navigate this list in reverse**.

A quick look at `bind -P` didn't show any obvious candidates for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you type <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> the direction is reversed. Typing it again revert back to the usual direction.

Some explanations are in `bash`'s man page:

```
       yank-last-arg (M-., M-_)
              Insert  the last argument to the previous command (the last word
              of the previous history entry).  With a numeric argument, behave
              exactly  like  yank-nth-arg.   Successive calls to yank-last-arg
              move back through the history list, inserting the last word  (or
              the  word  specified  by the argument to the first call) of each
              line in turn.  Any numeric argument supplied to these successive
              calls  determines  the direction to move through the history.  A
              negative argument switches the  direction  through  the  history
              (back or forward).  The history expansion facilities are used to
              extract the last argument, as if the "!$" history expansion  had
              been specified.
```

Comment: `Alt+- Alt+.` is easier to type and equivalent. But this isn't quite `Alt+.` in reverse: `Alt+- Alt+. Alt+- Alt+.` does not undo `Alt+. Alt+.`, it toggles between the last two values.

Answer (score 1):

Building on enzotib doc reference, you can hack-up a custom *reverse* command:

- `alt+-` - trigger reverse
- `alt+.` - accept first reversed result
- `alt+.` - accepted second reversed result
- `alt+-` - reverse again in proper direction
- `alt+.` - accept first reversed result

Assingnthe `alt+,` to this sequence in the readline config file (`~/.inputrc`)

```
"\e,": "\e-\e.\e.\e-\e."
```

Refresh terminal using `C-x C-r`
and now you have a reverse hack.